# LogParser - Issue with white spaces in URLs

Tags: logparser

I am unable to solve a problem in parsing IIS log records containing whitespaces in URLs. I have already implemented -dQuotes:On and the input format is W3C. Due to the whitespaces in URLs the complete URL is not captured and also wrong values are retrieved for subsequent fields in IIS log.

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Praveen

Comment: Can you post a sample log line? Also, are you using the "W3C" input format or the "IISW3C" input format? The latter is more convenient when parsing W3C log files generated by IIS.

Comment: #Fields:  date-local time-local s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken c-port

2016-09-18 12:14:41.852 "DEFAULT WEB SITE" "WEB-SERVER-18" 0.0.0.0 GET /Support/GetCode/Please contact Technical Support - 80 - "0.0.0.0" "HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)" - - "www.mywebsite.com" 404 0 -2147024894 1802 434 0 "52948"

Comment: I've posted the sample log in the above comment. In that log the URL looks like '/Support/GetCode/Please contact Technical Support' without any quotes around it. I have tried IISW3C as you suggested, but it's not returning any results. Seems that our logs are not IISW3C compliant

Comment: Definitely not W3C compliant either, as fields are supposed to be whitespace-separated. Are the fields may be separated by tabs? In that case you might try to set the `-separator` option to `tab`.